# C# - Making Textbox's Text Anti Aliased / Smooth

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, antialiasing

Is there any way of changing the text smoothing style of a textbox control? I tried to do the same thing I did to the label control, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
public partial class SmoothTextBox : TextBox
{

private TextRenderingHint _TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
public TextRenderingHint TextRendering {
    get { return _TextRenderingHint; }
    set {
        _TextRenderingHint = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

public New() : base()
{
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    Multiline = true;
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = _TextRenderingHint;
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have to use the UseCompatibleTextRendering property to true, just as I did with the Label control, but such property is not declared for the textbox control. Anything I could do?

By drawing a string is the close I could get, but I don't know how to manipulate it more to look normal and smooth.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = _TextRenderingHint;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(System.Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new Point(0, 0));
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Result: http://prntscr.com/eqpgd8

So the best I could think of, is making that tiny textbox at the same size of normal textbox, and having the forecolor set to the backcolor's color. But I'm not really into GDI+ at all, I don't know how to do it nor if it'll work.

Comment: What library is this? It looks like WinForms, you might want to tag your question with that to find someone who can answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited. Thank you!